# Getting Keyboard To Appear Without Having To Click on EditText

Tags: android

I am using a custom layout on an AlertDialog.  The custom layout has an EditText filed which I am using to get a phone.  When I display the AlertDialog, in order to get the keyboard to type in the phone number you have to click on the EditText filed.  Is there a way to get the keyboard to automatically pop up when I bring up the AlertDialog so that the user does not have to click on the EditText filed to get the Keyboard.

Thanks,
Prasanna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this line when you are showing your dialog:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```