# setSoftInputMode for a Dialog to not hide EditText while typing?

Tags: android, keyboard, dialog, android-edittext

I have a Custom Dialog that has an EditText at the bottom of the view. When I select the EditText, the keyboard comes up but hides the EditText within the Dialog..

I know that you can use windowSoftInputMode for an activity and the Reference says you can use 
Window.setSoftInputMode() 
for non activities.. But how to do this???

[Reference](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html)

I tried doing this
[Getting Keyboard To Appear Without Having To Click on EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181025/getting-keyboard-to-appear-without-having-to-click-on-edittext)

But after

Dialog.show();

i placed

getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

But nothing works..
Help Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```